# Open cart ... Different CSS per category

Tags: opencart

I am trying to load completely different CSS file per category in opencart shopping cart. I have tried to use switch statement in header.tpl but it did not help me.

Basically I have only four categories and all will have different CSS. Like category 56 has different, 57 different, 58 different and 59 different.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your desired css file, via `category.php` controller file.

**File:**

```
catalog/controller/product/category.php
```

**Find:**

```
$this->document->setTitle($category_info['meta_title']);
```

**Add before it:**

```
if($category_id == 20){
    $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/mytheme/stylesheet/category20.css');
}
```